# Google sheets lookup file by filename in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

is there a way to link to a file on Google drive by the filename?

I am listing data on a google sheet, and in the same folder, I have multiple pdf files corresponding to the data on the sheet. Say, `id: 1234` has a corresponding pdf file `1234.pdf`.

is there a way to quickly link to the file based on the filename?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

I believe the only way to achieve your goal is to use Google Apps Script and in particular the [DriveApp](http://Class%20DriveApp) class.

- The following script will get a column of names as input and it will return back to the sheet the urls for each name within a specified folder.
- It assumes that the name of the files are unique within this folder.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of your sheet
  const folder_id = "fid"; // put the folder id
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
  const names = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const urls = names.map(name=>[folder.getFilesByName(name+".pdf").next().getUrl()]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,urls.length,1).setValues(urls);   
}
```

From the script above adjust the following four things:

- Choose the name of your sheet; replace `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet.
- Put the folder id of your folder in `fid`.
- The file names are copied from column A and from the range `A2` until the last row with content. Choose the column where you have the name of the files.
- Adjust the starting cell you want to paste the columns. In my case `sh.getRange(2,2,..)` means start pasting from the cell `B2`.

**Sample sheet used for the script:**

[image]

Comment: forgive my ignorance, do I add this as an addon? and do I need to run it every time I want to update the sheet? I was thinking of some kind of lookup formula but this can work as well if I can do it as an add on.

Comment: @Joel you can create a macro button on the top menu of the spreadsheet file or run it as it is in the script editor. Go to tools and then script editor and put the code there. Click on the run button to execute.

Comment: what would be the script type? `Web app`, `API Executable`, `Add-on`, or `Library`?

Comment: @Joel bound Script....you just need to press the run button

Comment: got an error on line 7
`Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end`
and what is the folder id? the string in the URL of the folder following `folders/`?